# ¿Como crear un ISO con SSH pre-instalado y configurado?

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox

tengo un pequeño problema. Necesito poder acceder a una máquina virtual en modo sin cabeza (Headless mode) desde SSH. Sucede que necesito crear esta máquina virtual automáticamente (ya se hacerlo), pero que ya esté habilitado SSH para poder conectarme sin necesidad de entrar a la máquina instalar SSH, y configurarlo. Es decir, necesito una ISO que al crear la máquina virtual e iniciar la ya me pueda conectar sin tener que configurar la máquina con SSH. Sino que ya SSH ya esté pre configurado. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?.

Comment: Hola, Andre. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Este sitio es para preguntas relacionadas a programación. Podrías utilizar AskUbuntu o SuperUser para realizar las preguntas. Aún así, intenta añadir lo que has intentado y no algo muy genérico y que la pregunta no esté basada en opiniones de la comunidad sino esta podría ser calificada de forma negativa y procedería a cerrarse. Te invito a leer el siguiente enlace de cómo preguntar: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. Saludos.

Comment: No me está dejando en AskUbuntu. Es porque debo esperar 40 minutos correcto?